# iOS 13 NEHotspotConfigurationManager Auto-Join Wifi issues SSID nil

Tags: ios13, ssid, networkextension

As of iOS 13 when we request to join a WiFi network using the NEHotspotConfigurationManager, after a successful connection we may or may not be able to see the SSID using key kCNNetworkInfoKeySSID.

Our app relies on seeing the SSID to set its state (if they are connected to our WiFi network show one version else show another).

So far we've seen the issue on various devices (iPhone 8 Plus, iPhone 11) using iOS 13.1.

A device reboot fixes the problem. Has anyone else seen this behavior?